# yajra/laravel-datatables, Reply Slow

Tags: laravel

Summary of problem or feature request

The reply o load datatable is very slow, betwen 3-5seg

How can I optimize the data load?

when I did not use server inside it was much faster..

first of all, Thanks

Code snippet of problem

Controller

```
    public function list_user(){
    $users = User::all();
    $users->each(function ($users)
    {
        $users->role;
    });
    return datatables()->collection($users)->toJson();
    }
```

Js

```
function activar_tabla_users() {
$('#DataTableUser').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "searchDelay" : 500,
    "responsive": {
        orthogonal: 'responsive'
    },
    "language": {
        "url": '{!! asset('/plugins/datatables.net/latino.json') !!}'
    } ,
    "lengthMenu": [5,10, 25, 50, 75 ],
    "ajax":'{!! url('admin/list_user') !!}',
    columns: [
        {data: 'id' },
        {data: 'username'},
        {data: 'name',
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return row.name + ' ' + row.lastname;
            } 
        },
        {data: 'email'},
        {data: 'role.name',
            render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
            var html = ''
            if ( row.role.name == 'Administrador' )
            {
                html = '<span class="label label-danger" > <label style="width:80px;"> '+row.role.name+' </label></span>';

            }else {
                html = '<span class="label label-primary" > <label style="width:80px;"> '+row.role.name+' </label></span>';
            }
            return html;
            }
        }
        }],

});
}
activar_tabla_users();
```

Comment: how many users are there?  why are you calling role on the user but doing nothing with it?  `$user->role`

Comment: sorry , i have 1300 register
and role only two: member and admin

Comment: just in this line .  {data: 'role.name',    i use the relation role

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using server side to get table data. Don't call **all()** as it will get all.

Replace:

```
$users = User::all();
```

With:

```
$users = User::query();
```

This only renders the required data in data-table page.

And, don't use loop to get role. Use eager loading using **with();**

```
$users = User::query()->with('role');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = User::all();
$users->each(function ($users)
{
    $users->role;
});
```

with this the following?

```
$users = User::with('role');
```

Datatable adds pagination options automatically. if you use `all()` it calls all the data from the table.

Another thing is did you checked that it takes 2/3sec to get data from the server or does it takes this time to format the data in the view?

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
$users = User::all();
$users->each(function ($users)
{
    $users->role;
});
```

with this:

```
$users = User::with('role')->get();
```

This will use one db request instead of over 1k requests (you were making a call for each user to get their role).  If you display all 1300 users at once, only request the "page" you need with laravels built in pagination, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results

Comment: Thanks but , it is still slow  , around 2 seg

Comment: the pagination not is the problem, the problem is, that i recharg the page, the delay is 3 seg, and if change netx slide in the paginate is 3 seg too

Comment: you're not getting paginated results from the database, you're requesting all 1300 and then breaking them up and paginating them with javascript in the browser

Comment: but, datatable has auto paginate
i show "lengthMenu": [5,10, 25, 50, 75 ],
and generate 268 slide

Comment: it's generating 268 slides using all 1300 users you've given it, if you want better performance you need to paginate from the backend with Laravel and use a data table that can handle backend pagination